# Using @ symbol in string

Tags: c#, asp.net

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) says that:

> The @ symbol tells the string constructor to ignore escape characters and line breaks.

I try to append contain in `StringBuilder` like this.

```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   sb.Append(@"<test name="test_all">");
```

But it gives an error in `test_all`.

I got a solution for this using single quotes. `' '`:

```
sb.Append("<test name='layout_all'>");
```

But I don't understand as per document why `" "` does not work. Or am I missing something to understand?

Comment: You shouldn't write XML yourself, use for example the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx).

Comment: @CodeCaster - Even if OP was building whole XML structures, there is nothing in the question to suggest the use of `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: @Oded so? It certainly does look like he is, so it might be worth looking for a built-in library **like** that one or the [XmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx), for not reinventing the wheel's sake.

Comment: @CodeCaster - `XDocument` or even `XmlWriter` may be more suitable for construction of small XML snippets.

Comment: If you read [the latest version of that link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx), you will find the answer in section "Regular and Verbatim String Literals".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, `"` still has a special meaning in a verbatim string literal - you need to escape it, but in this case, you simply double it:

```
sb.Append(@"<test name=""test_all"">");
```